# User can't access site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, user-profile, user-profile-property

I have SP2016 and i grant access to a user to a site but the user can't access the site get "Sorry you don't have access". all other users can access except this one. I did search for the user in central admin-Manage User Profiles it shows Domain\userId-DELETED.
the Distinguished name "CN=userid, name,OU=AzureSync,OU=Vendors,OU=**** People,OU=****,DC=ad,DC=*****,DC=com
I did remove the user access from the site and add the user again but still the same. also tested another couple users who can access the site even in central admin-Manage User Profiles it shows Domain\userId-DELETED for both (not sure why it shows this).
I can reach user profile (My site) http://intranet-my.contoso.com/ but if i try to edit profile i get error "Sorry, something went wrong"

Not sure why user can't access and why it shows some users DELETED
Any help please.

Comment: Please provide images about the deleted user profile in CA. Also, check ULS file to find if there is anything about this issue. The default path of ULS files is: C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\LOGS.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. find out the user who left the company and came back. so solution is you need to delete user from site collection, this can be done by setting site collection url and in the end _layouts/15/people.aspx?MembershipGroupId=0 or go site settings -> Permissions -> select any group and change from end of the url number to 0. From list of users there find the user and delete it from site collection, then add again to the site and access for the user starts to work!

Comment: As this issue is solved, you can accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Active Directory authentication (and other platforms that require cloud-based authentication) assumes Tenant concept; and this concept contains this rule: one time user is deleted from any platform, this cannot be reversible. I have this trouble too, but with Office 365, when O365 was deployed at my region: I get several support joined with Microsoft, and one MS-Engineer guide me with this Tenant concept.